# How to convert object to json with jsonconvert - without - key-quotations

Tags: c#, json

I use jsonconvert to convert simple objects to json like

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { label = "MyLabel1" });
```

to

```
{ "label":"MyLabel1" }
```

but i want to get the keys without quotation like

```
{ label: "MyLabel1"}
```

is there a way to convert objects to json withoud "key"-quotations by using jsonconvert?

Comment: AFAIK, the second form is not JSON. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i need it for jquery plot-plugin "flot"....

Comment: Are you sure flot won't work correctly with quotes?

Comment: @svick is correct, JSON requires quoted keys. Any app or library that consumes JSON will accept (and probably expect) quotation marks around each key. Are you seeing an error or looking at documentation that suggests otherwise to you? I suspect you've misdiagnosed whatever problem you've encountered.

Comment: you are right... flot has no problems with double quoatations... it is only a problem between "Label" and "label"... in my objects properties in uppercase, but flot uses lowercase...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any library that expects JSON or actual JavaScript notation for creating objects (which is a superset of JSON) should work fine with quotes.

But if you really want to remove them, you can set `JsonTextWriter.QuoteName` to false. Doing this requires writing some code that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` uses by hand:

```
private static string SerializeWithoutQuote(object value)
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(null);

    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        jsonWriter.QuoteName = false;

        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Spongman `StringWriter.Dispose()` doesn't do anything, so I don't see any reason to put it into `using`.

Comment: it may not do anything _today_. but in the future it may. future-proof code will call Dispose regardless.

Comment: @Spongman What would it do? `StringWriter` doesn't have any unmanaged resources or anything like that. It's just memory and that's what the GC is for.

Comment: You're looking at one single implementation. How do you know it doesn't do anything on UWP, or the mice framework, or on the phone. No. Don't prematurely optimize (especially when you're giving advice on a public forum - this isn't the place to be showing off). He Api says it should be disposed, so that's what you should do.

Comment: @Spongman I'm also thinking about what could it possibly do. It's a `StringWriter`, it writes characters into memory and then builds a `string` out of them. What unmanaged resources could it possibly have? And this is not optimization (it doesn't make the code faster, it makes it shorter), so I don't see how calling it premature optimization makes sense, or how the common advice about premature optimization applies.

Answer (score 0):

I complement answer @svick. For save format you need use StringBuilder for StringWriter.

```
 static string SerializeWithoutQuote(object value)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder);
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jsonWriter.QuoteName = false;
            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```